# Order By column 2, group by column 1

Tags: sql, parent-child, mariadb

Maybe is the title not clear enough, but didn't knew an better way to say it.

The thing is that I've got an table called `Partij` which has an `idPartij` and an `Moederpartij`. The column `Moederpartij` will point back to `idPartij` ( so we can create an `Mother -> Child` relation ).

This is the Query I have so far:

```
SELECT 
       P.idPartij,
       P.Partijnaam,
       P.Gewicht,
       PER.Perceel,
       P.Moederpartij
FROM Partij AS P
LEFT OUTER JOIN Perceel AS PER ON P.idPerceel = PER.idPerceel
WHERE P.Actief = 1
ORDER BY 
       P.Moederpartij ASC,
       P.Partijnaam ASC
```

Which results in the following output:

```
360 | 34 Avarna 13-1V     |  |  0
280 | 36 Agata 13-1V      |  |  0
160 | 37 Excellency 13-1V |  |  0
140 | 38 Erika 13-1V      |  |  0
300 | 39 Rosagold 13-1V   |  |  0
240 | 40 Fontane 13-2V    |  |  0
200 | 41 Fontane 13-1V    |  |  0
220 | 42 Fontane 13-3V    |  |  0
180 | 45 Spunta 13-3V     |  |  0
260 | 46 Arnova 13-1V     |  |  0
400 | 43 Spunta 13-2V     |  |  180
380 | 44 Spunta 13-1V     |  |  180
320 | 35 Altus 13-1V      |  |  260
340 | 47 Arizona 13-1V    |  |  260
```

But I'm trying to get the following output:

```
360 | 34 Avarna 13-1V     |  |  0
280 | 36 Agata 13-1V      |  |  0
160 | 37 Excellency 13-1V |  |  0
140 | 38 Erika 13-1V      |  |  0
300 | 39 Rosagold 13-1V   |  |  0
240 | 40 Fontane 13-2V    |  |  0
200 | 41 Fontane 13-1V    |  |  0
220 | 42 Fontane 13-3V    |  |  0
180 | 45 Spunta 13-3V     |  |  0
400 | 43 Spunta 13-2V     |  |  180
380 | 44 Spunta 13-1V     |  |  180
260 | 46 Arnova 13-1V     |  |  0
320 | 35 Altus 13-1V      |  |  260
340 | 47 Arizona 13-1V    |  |  260
```

So that you first get the `Mother (Moederpartij)` And after that all the `Childs`, and so on...

Is this even possible in 1 single Query or should I loop in PHP through the records an get all the child for each record?

**EDIT 1**
The DB where this is running, is an `MariaDB`.

Comment: In which DB are you trying to achieve it Oracle / SQL Server / MySQL?

Comment: @AravinthKannan, It's an `MariaDB` server. Sorry for not pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. I had added an column in the select query and sorted based on it. Since I don't have the MariaDB have not tested the query but I am sure it shld solve ur query.

```
SELECT 
       P.idPartij,
       P.Partijnaam,
       P.Gewicht,
       PER.Perceel,
       P.Moederpartij,
       case when P.Moederpartij =0 then
       Concat(P.idPartij ,"-", "0","-", P.idPartij )
       else
       Concat(P.Moederpartij ,"-", "9","-", P.idPartij )
       end sorder
FROM Partij AS P
LEFT OUTER JOIN Perceel AS PER ON P.idPerceel = PER.idPerceel
WHERE P.Actief = 1
ORDER BY 
       sorder Asc
```

Comment: This is indeed where i was looking for! It works out of the box. Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your question, but is "Avarna 13-1V" for example the full party name, and the mother as you call it is "Avarna"?

I.e. you want all Spuntas, Fontanes etc. together but they also contain the 13-1V, 13-2V etc. and that's what throws it off?

You could order by just the first word first (locate the space separator & take the left of that), then by the mother party field. E.g. something like this:

ORDER BY LEFT(Partijnaam, LOCATE(' ',Partijnaam) - 1), Moederpartij

But if that is the case why not just separate the text name and the 13-v1 etc. into different columns?

(MySQL)

Comment: You're right about the `Party name`. And Most of the times they will be needed together, but... They will not always be tight together all. That's why I'm using an `mother child` relation by `ID`...

Comment: It's more work but if you'll be working with the data a lot in the long run you could consider breaking the mothers & children out into their own separate tables, then relate them with a foreign key. Then you can join the tables & do a lot more with the data without having to worry about string operations.

Comment: The way you are linking them together right now between the two columns gives more of the impression of a linked list, like each has a specific successor. You really just want groupings though, it sounds like. Manipulating the string in the order by would help you achieve that but defining these relationships relationally is always the best practice.

Comment: That is indeed the better way to handle this, and I've already considerd that and talked about it with the other dev's here. But that will be a LOT of work, because this table is also used in a lot of other products. So I hoped that there was an "clean" SQL way, before I would do it inside the PHP script...

Comment: What's the volume of data like? If it's a lot of records, then the PHP way could be inefficient & hard on your PHP server. Another option I just thought of is you could write a self join on the table on the ID to the mother, then pull out the MIN of the left two integers in the Partijnaam string, and order on that field. Either way I think your best option is string manipulation operators!

Comment: The data could be 10 - 1000> So that's why I didn't really wan't to use the script way because of the exact same reason. And that join was indeed an another option, but Aravinth Kannan gave an answer that works. But thank you very much for trying to solve this problem / thinking with me!